# Error replicating password change in MySQL slave

Tags: mysql, replication

So I built a master-slave Mysql replication architecture in production because of a database FOO that I wanted to query (slave node) without affecting the performance of the main site (master node).

The thing is, I was afraid of someone breaking replication by inserting data in the slave which would conflict with data coming from master, so as soon as I created the slave node, I removed all privileged users (e.g. dba1, dba2) in the slave node and added a single readonly one (with the SELECT grant): readonlyUser.

The problem I have now is that suddenly `dba1` has changed his password in the master node, and the result is this replication error:

```
Replication reported error 1396:
Error 'Operation ALTER USER failed for 'dba1'@'localhost'' on query. 
Default database: 'mysql'.
Query: 'ALTER USER 'dba1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*DAB3A57F75AD41285552E115420DA2EFD756CD19''
```

Should I prevent the replication of the `mysql` DB then? I'm afraid that, if I do this, any structure changes for my FOO database will not be replicated, because the structure of the tables is stored in the `mysql` database, right?

Or should I just ignore errors of type 1396? Is error1396 always related to users or is it more broad?

Comment: What versions of mysql on Master and Slave?

Comment: slave has 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 and master has 5.7.12, why?

Answer (score -1):

Mysql Replication is pretty hard to manage, if anyone executed wrong query it'll affect the slave too. Use the below command to fix.

> Stop slave;
>
> SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1; START SLAVE;

If you want to exclude this error all time, add the below line in my.cnf file.

If the error code is 1396 then

> slave-skip-errors = 1396

Comment: alright, so I asked in my question **if just ignoring 1396 would not be hiding other important errors**? are you sure that 1396 is only related to updating passwords? is there any documentation out there?

Comment: also, I've tried your first solution, and that makes replication not work at all (I've tried to insert a row in master, and slave doesn't receive it)

Comment: This is a workaround, not an answer.